# Javascript array.prototype being printed almost everywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Since I had to remove some elements from my arrays, I followed a few pieces of code found in stackoverflow and came up with this one:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(from, to) {
  var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
  this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;
  return this.push.apply(this, rest);
};
```

For some reasons, however, this piece of code is being printed EVERYWHERE whenever something has something to with an array.

Example:

this piece of code:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(from, to) {
  var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
  this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;
  return this.push.apply(this, rest);
};

Scadenza.prototype.init = function() {
    this.promemoria = (this.promemoria == "")?("NO"):(this.promemoria);
    var gruppo = this.group; // convert array to string.
    this.group = "";
    for (var i in gruppo) {
        if (i != (gruppo.length - 1)) {
            this.group += gruppo[i] + ", ";
        }
        else {
            this.group += gruppo[i];
        }
    }
    alert(this.group);
};
```

This piece of code is supposed to convert the array this.group (stored  temporarily in the variable "gruppo") into a string (that's quite obvious, I think).

It is, of course, doing it's job greatly, if it wouldn't be that its alert is:

> [DATA NEEDED]function (from, to) { var rest = this.slice((to || from)
>   + 1 || this.length); this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from; return this.push.apply(this, rest); }

This piece of code is being also sent to a database through an AJAX request and the result of the query, at the desired coloumn, is this one:

> function (from, to) {  var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 ||
>   this.length);  this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from; 
>   return this.push.apply(this, rest); },

I'm quite surprised this is happening but I have ABSOLUTELY no idea on how to fix it.

No errors have been alerted while loading the page or when clicking the button that throws this event.

Any idea?

ps: Not sure if helps, but I'm using jQuery.

@comments:

The normal for loop actually doesn't fix this:

```
Scadenza.prototype.init = function() {
    this.promemoria = (this.promemoria == "")?("NO"):(this.promemoria);
    var gruppo = this.group; // convert array to string.
    this.group = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < gruppo.length; i++) {
        if (i != (gruppo.length - 1)) {
            this.group += gruppo[i] + ", ";
        }
        else {
            this.group += gruppo[i];
        }
    }
    alert(this.group);
};
```

Alert is still the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

Comment: It doesn't work either with a normal for loop, thanks.

Comment: It does. Maybe you didn't fix all occurrences of `for in` loops… What does `this.group` contain? Maybe the `.toString()` methods of the items do it wrong as well.

Comment: It's better to use console.log instead of alert to debug your code. In chrome press F12 to open the developer tools and the console. In Firefox press control+shift + k. Then you can add information to your log like `console.log("in for i<arr.length loop",this.group)` the console.log takes a variable amount of parameters so you can log multiple things in one command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use proper `for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)` loops for iterating arrays. [`for in` enumerations will enumerate prototype properties as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea), do not use them on arrays. You are doing that in your `init` method for example.

Btw, for that task you want to use [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) anyway:

```
Scadenza.prototype.init = function() {
    if (this.promemoria == "")
        this.promemoria = "NO";
    this.group = this.group.join(", "); // convert array to string
    alert(this.group);
};
```

Comment: After removing array.prototype.remove and using .join it fixed it, thanks! Any idea, however, why this was happening even with normal for loops?

Comment: I didn't say to remove `Array.prototype.remove`. It does not happen with normal loops. Either you had some caching issue with the code, or you overlooked an occurrence of `for in` (maybe in the `this.group[i].toString` methods?). Please provide a self-contained example that exhibits this behaviour if you still are suffering from the issue.

Comment: For some reason this fixed it, no more random functions parsed anymore, but I surely won't use (for variable in array) anymore with arrays, thanks! Is it suitable for objects, anyway?

Comment: Yes, it is OK for plain objects. `Object.prototype` will never contain enumerable properties.

Comment: @Bergi There is a rare case when you set only a couple of elements in the array that are far apart: `arr[0]=1;arr[1000]=2` you should use for in with hasOwnProperty `for(key in arr){if(arr.hasOwnProperty(key){...do stuff here`

Answer (score 3):

When you change the `Array` prototype, the method is added to the Array object as a new attribute. When you iterate with `for (var attr in object)` you are iterating over the object and all of its attributes. Therefore, your new method is included in that loop.

You need to use a `for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++)` loop. That will only include items in the array.

Comment: As already posted above, this doesn't fix it! I'm still getting the same alert...

Comment: can you show us how you are assigning this.group before it is assigned to `gruppo` in your `init` method?

Comment: I've fixed it using the .join, anyway, this.group was assigned by taking values from checkboxes, pushing them into an array. Maybe there is something wrong there, but using .join fixed it!